# How does compareTo() work

Tags: java, collections

I read some answers regarding the `compareTo()` function but I'm still not clear about how it works internally.

I have the below code snippet which I am trying to understand.

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private long salary;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public long getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public Employee(int id, String name, int age, int salary) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Employee emp) {
        //let's sort the employee based on id in ascending order
        //returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this employee id
        //is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.
        return (this.id - emp.id);
    }

}
```

And one `CompareClass` as:

```
public class CompareClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Employee[] empArr = new Employee[4];
        empArr[0] = new Employee(10, "Mikey", 25, 10000);
        empArr[1] = new Employee(20, "Arun", 29, 20000);
        empArr[2] = new Employee(5, "Lisa", 35, 5000);
        empArr[3] = new Employee(1, "Pankaj", 32, 50000);

        //sorting employees array using Comparable interface implementation
        Arrays.sort(empArr);
        System.out.println("Default Sorting of Employees list:\n"+Arrays.toString(empArr));

    }

}
```

So when `Arrays.sort(empArr)` is called,  then inside `compareTo()`, which is the `this.id` and which is `emp.id`?

Basically I am trying to understand, when `compareTo()` is called, then `employee` object from `empArr` becomes the current object and then, with which object it is getting compared.

```
return (this.id - emp.id);
```

So what is `this` and `emp`?

Comment: the `sort` method calls `compareTo` on the instances in the array that need to be compared during the sort. There is no 'current object', this is driven by the implementation of the sort algo.

Comment: It works just like any other function.  It's called on some instance, and it has a parameter.

Comment: You'll find it a lot easier to understand if you write it as `public int compareTo(Employee that)`. All you are doing is comparing `this` to `that`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so what is "this" and "emp" ?

Well, look at what method you are writing! It's the `compareTo` method. It can be called like this:

```
a.compareTo(b)
```

In this case, `a` is `this`, `b` is `emp`.

But what actually is `this` and `emp` *when the `sort` method calls `compareTo`*?

To find this out, you need to look at how `sort` is implemented. In my version of the JDK, `sort` eventually calls a method called `binarySort` declared in `ComparableTrimSort.class`. In `binarySort`, there are these lines:

```
while (left < right) {
    int mid = (left + right) >>> 1;
    if (pivot.compareTo(a[mid]) < 0) // <--- here is the compareTo call
        right = mid;
    else
        left = mid + 1;
}
assert left == right;
```

`sort` might call `compareTo` in lots of other places as well. My suggestion is to not care about what `sort` does, just implement the `compareTo` method. Return a value indicating whether `this` is equal, less than, or greater than the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the parameter on the `compareTo` function it has `"Employee emp"` as the parameter, Employee being the type and emp being the name used to refer to it. In order to compare an object with another, you use one of the objects and use the compareTo function to compare it with another one. Because of this you need a way to refer to the current object being used, int this case we use `this` in order to have access to the variables inside the object, and emp to refer to the Employee that was passed as a parameter. In this case, `this` is not necessary to get the id of the current object, but in other cases you need to do it if there is a local variable with the same name.